# Unable to reboot from USB on Snow Leopard

Tags: snow-leopard

I have an external hard disk, where I had stored my 10.5.8 image. The laptop had issues with keyboard and display, so I stopped using it. I have a relatively new(5 months old) Snow Leopard Mac book Pro.I also have a mini mac. When I reboot the mac mini with the 10.5.8 image, it works fine. But with MBP, when I reboot, it sits at the apple image and does nothing.

The image was created using SuperDuper. I basically have an option in superduper to copy the hard disk to a usb. I think it blindly copie the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your new MBP has few hardware components that are not supported by Mac OS X 10.5.8. Just to be sure you can check where 10.5.8 chocking when booting MBP if you press and hold <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> during boot.

Answer (score -1):

A MacBook Pro that shipped with Snow Leopard will not boot from any version of Mac OS X lower than the version that was installed when it shipped.

Comment: That is not true since it's totally possible to run older OS on many variants of MBP that was initially shipped with new one if driver support is present in older OS.